# How can I parse the WebResponse XML to get a specific node using VB.NET?

Tags: xml, vb.net, soap

I am trying to connect to a website and read the returned XML.  This is my first attempt at using SOAP.
The issue is that I can return the XML but need to parse it to grab the value.

Here is my code that will return the response:

```vb
Dim request As HttpWebRequest = CreateWebRequest()
Dim soapEnvelopeXml As New XmlDocument()

Try
    soapEnvelopeXml.LoadXml("<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>" & vbCr & vbLf _
                            & "           <soap:Envelope " _
                            & "           xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" " _
                            & "           xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" " _
                            & "           xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">" & vbCr & vbLf _
                            & "             <soap:Body>" & vbCr & vbLf _
                            & "               <AccountLogin xmlns=""http://api.filesanywhere.com/"">" & vbCr & vbLf _
                            & "                 <APIKey>" & sAPIKey & "</APIKey>" & vbCr & vbLf _
                            & "                 <OrgID>" & iOrgID & "</OrgID>" & vbCr & vbLf _
                            & "                 <UserName>" & sUserName & "</UserName>" & vbCr & vbLf _
                            & "                 <Password>" & sPassword & "</Password>" & vbCr & vbLf _
                            & "                 <AllowedIPList>" & sAllowedIPList & "</AllowedIPList>" & vbCr & vbLf _
                            & "                 <ClientEncryptParam>" & sClientEncryptParam & "</ClientEncryptParam>" & vbCr & vbLf _
                            & "            </AccountLogin>" & vbCr & vbLf _
                            & "            </soap:Body>" & vbCr & vbLf _
                            & "            </soap:Envelope>")

    Using stream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
        soapEnvelopeXml.Save(stream)
    End Using

    Using response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
        Using rd As New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
            Dim soapResult As String = rd.ReadToEnd()
            Form1.TextBox1.Text = soapResult.ToString()
        End Using
    End Using

Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

And here is the SOAP Response:
[SOAPResponse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRx5M.jpg)

What I would like to do is to assign the Token and ErrorMessage node values to text boxes.

I've tried this approach that I found on this site but it is not working for me.  I had this added to my code block right after textBox1.Text.

```vb
Dim doc As New XmlDocument
doc.LoadXml(soapResult)
Dim nsm = New XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable)
nsm.AddNamespace("a", "http://api.filesanywhere.com/")
TextBox2.Text = doc.SelectSingleNode("/a:AccountLoginResult/a:LoginResult/a:Token", nsm).InnerText
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Posting the response XML as an image makes it much harder to help you parse it.  Also, any reason you are manually building/parsing the SOAP XML vs. using a [web reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tydxdyw9(v=vs.100).aspx)?  Perhaps see [mcve].

Comment: I have been asked to do a project to build and parse the SOAP XML without using the web reference.  I would rather use the web reference but the person who asked specifically did not want me to use it.

Comment: That's a good reason. :-)  I rarely use XPath (I prefer [LINQ to XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt692806.aspx)), but try a double slash at the beginning of the query - `TextBox2.Text = doc.SelectSingleNode("//a:AccountLoginResult/a:LoginResult/a:Token", nsm).InnerText` - otherwise I think you have to match the full path to the element.

Comment: I just noticed in your response XML image that it is actually `<AccountLoginResponse xmlns...>` and you are checking for `a:AccountLoginResult`, so that probably explains the NRE (since it won't find the node) - so `doc.SelectSingleNode("//a:AccountLoginResponse/a:LoginResult/a:Token", nsm)` should work (`//` is descendent-or-self).  Edit: This now applies to the comment below (I am not really psychic).

Comment: I wound up coding it this way because the above was giving me an object not set to reference error:<br/>    'Now get the response...
Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
doc.LoadXml(soapResult.ToString())
Dim root As XmlNode = doc.DocumentElement
Dim nsmgr As New XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable)
nsmgr.AddNamespace("al", "http://api.filesanywhere.com/")
Dim nodeToken As XmlNode = root.SelectSingleNode("descendant::al:Token", nsmgr)
sToken = nodeToken.InnerText